# Help in fpdf imade display

Tags: php

Hello every one i m using fpdf libray to creat pdf files from html form.

i m using

```
$pdf->Image('C:/DOCUME%7E1/mypic.PNG',60,140,120,0,'','');
```

to display image on pdf.

in its first parameter it asks for exact path.it doesn't accept anyaddress variable here.
but i want to make dynamic.i have able to get a complete path in an variable.

i have printed this variable.

```
//////////////////////////////
echo "$path";
```

output

```
////////////////////
C:/DOCUME%7E1/mypic.PNG
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

but how i put that path from variable in this parameter.?
when i use this variable as in this function.it give error.

```
$pdf->Image('$path',60,140,120,0,'','');
```

plz help me for this.

Comment: Do you realize the difference between *string* `'$path'` and *variable* `$path`?

Comment: note that '$var' is not the same thing as "$var"

Answer (score 3):

```
$pdf->Image($path,60,140,120,0,'','');
```

This should work.
I removed the single quotes from the variable.

OR

put the `$path` in double quotes:-

```
 $pdf->Image("$path",60,140,120,0,'','');
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single quotes wrapping the variable name.

The single quotes make PHP treat your string as a literal (i.e. `$path` instead of `C:/DOCUME%7E1/mypic.PNG`).

Confusingly, it *would* work with double quotes because of variable interpolation.